# How to join table in Flask + Sqlalchemy and get nested json

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I have 3 tables.

```
User:
userId|userName|fullName

Event:
eventId|eventName

EventGroupInfo:
eventId|userId|isAdmin
```

Now I want list of events of particular `userId` and each event should contain `userList` (with parameter as `userId`,`userName`, `fullName`, `isAdmin`)

I tried with marshmallow but I am getting only `userId` and `isAdmin` in `userList` inside each event object.

```
Current Response:
{
"events": [
    {
        "eventId": 41,
        "eventName": "Movie",
        "userList": [
            {
                "userId": 40,
                "isAdmin":True
            },
            {
                "userId": 50,
                "isAdmin":False
            }
           ]
          }
         ]
        }
```

Expected Response:

```
{
"events": [
    {
        "eventId": 41,
        "eventName": "Movie",
        "userList": [
            {
                "userId": 40,
                "userName:"xyz",
                "fullName":""   
                "isAdmin":True
            },
            {
                "userId": 50,
                "userName":"abc",
                "fullName":"",
                "isAdmin":False
            }
           ]
          }
         ]
        }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and post some additional informations like how you've defined your models, which python package you've used (I guess marschmallow)? If you've used masrchmallow how do you define your UserSchema, EventSchema, EventGroupInfoSchema? Documentation for this pachage --> https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/